# PHP: take a path from site root given an absolute path

Tags: php, root

Maybe a dumb question: given a full path like:

```
C:/wamp/www/acme/archivio/subfolder/C00005/FATCLI/2014-V00011.pdf
```

and given that site root is `acme`, how can I get the part:

```
/archivio/subfolder/C00005/FATCLI/2014-V00011.pdf
```

in the easiest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode` -

```
$path = 'C:/wamp/www/acme/archivio/subfolder/C00005/FATCLI/2014-V00011.pdf';

$paths = explode('acme', $path);

echo $paths[1];
```

[explode()](http://php.net/explode)

You can `variable` also -

```
$root = 'acme';
$paths = explode($root, $path);
```